# Why the method of substitution become wrong in this question?

Tags: alternative-proof, substitution

The question says:

> Suppose that $f^{-1}$ is the inverse function of $f$ and $y=f^{-1}(-x)$ is the inverse function of $y=f(-x)$; prove $f(x)$ is an odd function.

Now I know one of the solution is to make $g(x)=-x$ and use the features of composite function.
But what I can't understand is that when I let $t=-x$, I think $f^{-1}(t)$ is the inverse function of $y=f(t)$, but this seems to suggest that $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f$.

Comment: $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f$, what's the issue?

Comment: @ultralegend5385 The two condition the problem give are equal to each other and that is strange.You can see previous edited version of my description.

Comment: Can you re-check the question; it seems like the problem might be "$f^{-1}(-x)$ is the inverse function of $f(x)$" or "$f^{-1}(x)$ is the inverse of $f(-x)$"?

Comment: $$
f^{-1}\left( x \right) =f^{-1}\left( g\left( x \right) \right) =\left( f^{-1}\circ g \right) \left( x \right) ,
\\
f\left( -x \right) =f\left( g\left( x \right) \right) =\left( f\circ g \right) \left( x \right) ,
\\
f^{-1}\circ g\,\,is\,\,the\,\,inverse\,\,function\,\,of\,\,f\circ g,
\\
f\circ g=\left( f^{-1}\circ g \right) ^{-1}=g^{-1}\circ f,
\\
f\left( -x \right) =\left( f\circ g \right) \left( x \right) =\left( g^{-1}\circ f \right) \left( x \right) =-f\left( x \right) 
\\
So\,\,f\,\,is\,\,an\,\,odd\,\,function.
$$

Comment: I copy the proof from my book and don't know whether it is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having already substituted $t=-x$ in $y=f(-x)$, you cannot *also* substitute it in $y=f^{-1}(-x)$ as this would be a different substitution. In this second case, $x$ belongs to the co-domain rather than domain of $f$. In fact, let's swap the variables $x$ and $y$ immediately, so that $x$ is in the domain and $y$ is in the co-domain: $x=f^{-1}(-y)$, and so the correct substitution there is $t=-f^{-1}(-y)$ rather than "$y=f^{-1}(t)$".

Comment: Thanks you,that's what I want!  your answer helps me to think more. However another issue comes to confuse me:$$
f^{-1}\left( -f\left( -x \right) \right) =-x,
\\
-f\left( -x \right) =f\left( -x \right) 
$$
It seems that f is a even function.  I can't find where the misktake is, or may I open another new question and invite you?

Comment: How did you get $f^{-1}(-f(-x))=-x$? I would expect you to have $f^{-1}(-f(-x))=x$.

Comment: $g^{-1}\left( g\left( x \right) \right) =x$ give me a feeling that obejct "x" is operated under $g$ and $g^{-1}$, so "-x" seems to operated under $f$ and $f^{-1}$.That's why I write down "-x" to right of the final equals sign.I habitually wrongly use the method of substitution. Even now I couldn't convert the two function in question to this form $g^{-1}\left( g\left( x \right) \right) =x$ directly. I should change to think $f(-x)$ as $f(g(x))$ and $g(x)=-x$ to follow the chain rule.Fortunately, I think it's enough for me.Thank you very much.